# HTTP Get fails to retrieve jpeg hosted on Amazon EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-ec2, twilio

I've developed a java web app that uses a jetty server to host images publicly (such as the image `http://52.23.50.128:8080/reports/94109_17_03_21_14.jpeg`), and then uses the twilio api to grab that image from a provided link, and shoot the image off in an SMS.

When I run the application locally, and use ngrok to expose my local machine to a publicly accessible URL (such as in `e0f5c759.ngrok.io/reports/94109_17_03_21_14.jpeg`), the application works fine. However, when I run my application on my AWS Lightsail EC2 Instance, and try to fetch the images from there (such as with `52.23.50.128:8080/reports/94109_17_03_21_14.jpeg` or `osterbox.com/reports/94109_17_03_21_14.jpeg`), the SMS is never sent.

When I look at twilios debugger, I can see that the SMS never sends due to an HTTP connection failure. Specifically, in the response header I see:

```
Date Tue, 21 Mar 2017 21:44:01 GMT
Last-Modified Tue, 21 Mar 2017 21:44:00 GMT
Content-Type image/jpeg
Accept-Ranges bytes
Content-Length 77695
Server Jetty(9.3.3.v20150827)
X-Cache MISS from ip-172-18-7-38.ec2.internal
X-Cache-Lookup MISS from ip-172-18-7-38.ec2.internal:3128
```

Does anyone know why the HTTP Get request would fail?

Comment: do you send the image via SMS or just you send the link of the image??? And do you send SMS based on the request by the other user or just you send.

Comment: Good questions, thanks SSingh. I just send twilio a link of the image, and have edited my original post to make this clear. I do so with Message.creator from the com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account Java package. I setMediaUrl to the url of the image.
My app sends the SMS based on the request of the user, but even when I do this with images that are pre-existing (and don't need to be generated on the fly) the issue occurs

Comment: *HTTP connection failure.*  You'll find that `X-Cache-Lookup: MISS` is not in fact an error at all.  This is succeeding.

Comment: I see, thanks Michael. I guess that this is a straightforward "Connection failure when fetching MediaUrl."

I appreciate the answer to my original question. While I've got your attention - Do you happen to know what would cause this? I've contacted Twilios support team to see if they can provide any more insight into the error, because I was under the impression that a URL is a URL as far as twilio is concerned - if both my locally hosted URL and EC2s URL are publicly accessible, why would one work and not the other?

Comment: What HTTP status are you seeing as the response to Twilio trying to retrieve the image?

Comment: I'm not getting a whole lot of detail from Twilio on the error. I'm pretty sure this is the extent of it: http://imgur.com/a/dOza7
(Unless there's some sort of "verbose" mode to their debugger I'm not aware of)